# SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow - Option not available

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

We are using SharePoint Online, I wanted to created a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow. But I am getting the following message:

> "The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available
>   because the workflow service is not configured on the server. Please
>   contact your server administrator."

I have seen this question asked earlier but they were all referring to on perm versions. Wanted to check if I can do anything from my side to work with 2013 workflows on SharePoint Online. I do not have access to anything except the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask You admin to enable the preview feature in order to create 2013 workflow.

Please help check if your Preview Feature is enable. If not, please enable it.

1. Go to tenant **Admin Center** at:  https://%3cdomain%3e-admin.sharepoint.com/
2. Click **Settings** in the **left navigation**
3. Check whether Enable preview features is **Enabled**, or **Disabled**

[image]
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/234418

Another thing,what is your O365 Plan type?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. We are using Office 365 Government Plans. I got a reply from MS support that they haven't updated SP 2013 Workflows in any of the government plans. https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/352948

Comment: yes, it is not avaiable in Govt 2013 Plan that's why i asked at the end your plan type...